# Parsing a string and differentiating between single character operators and double character operators

Tags: java, methods, operators, token

I am new to programming and I am creating a programme that parses a string and prints out a line number, TokenType and the character.

In it, I have successfully got it to print out operators with the line number they are and their TokenType. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to differentiate between single-character operators like '+' and double character operators like "<=" when I am printing them. I have methods that determine if they are single or double operators successfully.

```
public static TokenType getOp (String s) {
    
    switch(s) {
    
    case "<=":
        return TokenType.OP_LESSEQUAL;  
        // contiuue for the rest of the double charatcer operators
    }   
}


public static TokenType getOp (char ch) {

    switch(ch) {
    
    case '+':
        return TokenType.OP_ADD;    
        // contiuue for the rest of the double charatcer operators
}

//similar methods for Symbols, Keywords, Letters, Numbers etc
```

I created a method that takes a string parameter and in it, I have logic that decides what to print and if something is a letter, number etc. What could I use to differentiate between single and double character operators?

```
public static void scan (String prog) {
    
            int n = prog.length();
            int index = 0;
            int lineNumber = 1;
            
            while (index < n) {
                
                char ch = prog.charAt(index);
                
                boolean whiteSpace = isWhiteSpace(ch);
                boolean newLine = isLineBreak(ch);
                TokenType sym = getSymbol(ch);
                TokenType op = getOp(ch);
                boolean letter = isLetter(ch);
                boolean digit = isDigit(ch);
                
                
                if (whiteSpace) {
                    
                        if (newLine) {
                            
                            lineNumber++;
                        } 
                    index++;    
                    continue;
                        
                    
                }
                
                else if (sym != null) {
                    System.out.println(lineNumber + "," + sym + ", " + ch);
                    index++;
                    continue;
                }
                
                else if (op != null) {
                    System.out.println(lineNumber + "," + op + ", " + ch);      
                    index++;
                    continue;
                }
```

At the moment this prints the following for a double character operator:

```
12,OP_GREATER, >
12,OP_ASSIGN, =
```

What I want is:

```
12, OP_GREATEREQUAL, >=
```

Apologies if this post is messy, it is my first. Any help is very much appreciated. Also, as this is a challenge I have been given I would prefer not to simply have my code written for me but would rather receive examples of a solution or be informed of something i can use to complete it on my own.

Comment: When you do `TokenType op = getOp(ch)` instead of passing a character pass a string (substring) of the operator index - 1 with a length of 3. For example `"var c = 4 += 1;"` in this string you'd get the value before and after the operator '+' and Trim the string, it should give you the correct `TokenType`. In C# you'd do `var index = line.IndexOf(ch); var found = line.Substring(index - 1, 3).Trim()`.

Comment: @Bargros I understand a portion of that solution but not all of it. It is possible for you to clarify any further? I have been programming for two weeks and just about everything I encounter is new. In this case, could you clarify what the operator index refers too? Aplogies for the presumibly simple questions.